# Rounding a percentage in Python

Tags: python

```
if act == "block" and enemy_decision != 2:
    percentage_blocked = (enemy_attack - block)/(enemy_attack) * 100
    print("You have blocked %s percent of the enemy's attack." % percentage_blocked)
```

From this I am getting numbers such as 82.113124523242323.  How can I round this percentage to the 10th place e.g. 82.1.

Comment: you can use: math.ceil

See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518641/how-to-round-off-a-floating-number-in-python

Comment: Beware: a floating point number cannot precisely represent the value 82.1. The closest it can get is 82.099999999999994315658113919198513031005859375. It will still appear as 82.1 when you print it, though.

Answer (score 4):

I think the standard round function should work

```
round(percentage_blocked,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the template string like this and `{0:.1f}` means, the first parameter has to be formatted to be with 1 decimal digit

```
print("You have blocked {0:.1f} percent of the enemy's attack.".format(percentage_blocked))
```

Comment: Note that if you blocked 0.04% of the attack, this will say "You blocked 0.0 percent of the attack". Same with 99.95%, it will say "100.0 percent".

Answer (score 3):

You could use `{:.1%}` format:

```
blocked = (enemy_attack - block) / enemy_attack
print("You have blocked {:.1%} percent of the enemy's attack.".format(blocked))
```

Notice: there is no `* 100`.

Answer (score 1):

```
print("You have blocked %.1f percent of the enemy's attack." % percentage_blocked)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution.

```
percentage_blocked = int(
           ((enemy_attack - block)/(enemy_attack) * 100)*10 + 0.5)/10
```

Round it while calculating. `int(x+0.5)` rounds x properly