# Round the number with 2 digits after DOT

Tags: python-2.7

val = 345.09874

now i want output like 345.10, 345.09 and 345.099 in python 2.7

Please help me.

Comment: Please help us, and help yourself, by searching the damn site before posting. This question has been answered thousands of times across the Internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to round off a floating number in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518641/how-to-round-off-a-floating-number-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Just to encourage you I am providing the answer, but next time you should google first.

Use this:

`print round(val,2)`

Answer (score 0):

I could get 2 out of 3 values using:

```
val = 345.09874
print("%.2f" % round(val,2)) #345.10
print("%.3f" % round(val,3)) #345.099
```

I dont know how to get the output with 345.09