# Simple way to round floats when printing

Tags: python

I am working on a project where it has to take user inputs and do calculations.

What I am aiming for is the print to appear as

> Inform the customer they saved 0.71 today

Not

> Inform the customer they saved 0.7105000000000001 today

Is there something I can put into the same line of code with the print function to have it be rounded? Or do I have to modify each variable.

I can post my code if requested.

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518641/how-to-round-off-a-floating-number-in-python).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the builtin `round()` function and float formatting:

```
>>> print "{0:0.2f}".format(round(x, 2))
0.71
```

**Some Notes:**

- `{0.2f}` will format a float to 2 decimal places.
- `round(x, 2)` will round up to 2 decimal places.

*Side Note:* `round()` is really necessary IHMO if you want to "round" the number before "display". It really depends on what you're doing!

Comment: `round` is unnecessary

Comment: Depends if you want to round up as well as format the float :)

Comment: I will try to use this in my code. Can someone explain to me exactly what .2f means? I just want to understand my own code

Comment: @JohnV it's explained in the string formatting mini language here https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec

Answer (score 2):

round() is return the floating point value number rounded to ndigits digits after the decimal point. which takes as first argument the number and the second argument is the precision

```
no = 0.7105000000000001
print round(no, 2)
```

second solution:

```
print "%.2f" % 0.7105000000000001
```

Answer (score 0):

use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html) instead of round()

```
from decimal import *

print(round(8.494,2)) # 8.49
print(round(8.495,2)) # 8.49
print(round(8.496,2)) # 8.5


print(Decimal('8.494').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)) #8.49
print(Decimal('8.495').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)) #8.50
print(Decimal('8.496').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)) #8.50
```

Comment: Why is `decimal` better than `round` in this case?