# How to round decimal digits always up

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

So i ran into trouble rounding floats up, this is my code:

```
foo = float(0.21)
bar = float(0.871929)

foobar = foo * bar
Rfoobar = round(foobar,2)
```

This gives me:

```
foobar = 0.1831
Rfoobar = 0.18
```

But i want Rfoobar to be `0.19`, 
how do i accomplish that it always rounds up the digits when there is a remainder?

I read about `math.ceiling` but in my case that doesn't seem to do the trick.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Multiply by 100, ceiling, divide by 100.

Comment: @Tom Zych You should put that in an answer, because it's totally what I would have done if not for your comment. ;-)

Comment: You've read [_how to round off a floating number in python_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518641/how-to-round-off-a-floating-number-in-python)?

Comment: Yep, good catch, duplicate.

Comment: @TomZych  How come i didn't think of that duh, i need more coffee!
Thanks for the help, that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the decimal point before and after calling `ceil`:

```
from math import ceil

Rfoobar = ceil(foobar * 100) / 100
```

If the number of decimals varies, you can do something like:

```
Rfoobar = ceil(foobar * 10 ** digits) / 10 ** digits
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also add 0.005 before rounding:

```
>>> for foobar in 0.1831, 0.1801, 0.1800:
        print(foobar, '->', round(foobar + 0.005, 2))

0.1831 -> 0.19
0.1801 -> 0.19
0.18 -> 0.18
```